# Unrecognized function or variable 'plotGrid'

Tags: matlab

I'm using MATLAB R2022b.

and I get the error :
Unrecognized function or variable 'plotGrid'.

when I use plotGrid. I thought I'm using it wrongly, so I copy pasted an example of MATLAB that is using it:
https://au.mathworks.com/help/5g/ug/nr-channel-estimation-using-csirs.html

But still get the same error. I have installed SImBiology and I have checked it. It is installed.
My machine is mac btw. And I have moved my code's folder to where the "Examples" in MATLAB is, just in case the path matters.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalled SimBiology and reinstalled. It works now. I think moving the folder to the same folder as MATLAB also have helped because I had tried uninstall/install before.